# Jquery fancy product designer

Tags: jquery

I am recently using `jquery` Fancy product designer and I am experiencing the following problem.
I want to use the product price for calculation but I cannot find a way to do it.

the code is:
 //event handler when the price is changing

```
$('#clothing-designer').bind('priceChange', function(evt, price, currentPrice) {
    $('#thsirt-price').text(currentPrice);
});
```

and the HTML is:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
PRICE <span class="price badge badge-inverse"><span id="thsirt-price"></span> €</span>
</div>
```

How do I get the price in numeric form?

The extra code is

```
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.removeElement = function(element) {

    if(typeof element === 'string') {
        element = thisClass.getElementByTitle(element);
    }

    if(element.params.price != 0 && !element.params.uploadZone) {
        currentPrice -= element.params.price;
        $elem.trigger('priceChange', [element.params.price, currentPrice]);
    }

    $contextDialog.find('.fpd-content-layers .fpd-list').children('[id="'+element.id+'"]').remove();

    stage.remove(element);

    if(element.params.hasUploadZone) {

        //check if upload zone contains objects
        var objects = stage.getObjects(),
            uploadZoneEmpty = true;
        for(var i=0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
            var object = objects[i];
            if(object.visible && object.params.replace == element.params.replace) {
                uploadZoneEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        var uploadZoneObject = _getUploadZone(element.params.replace);

        uploadZoneObject.opacity = uploadZoneEmpty ? 1 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * Gets fired as soon as an element has been removed.
     *
     * @event FancyProductDesigner#elementRemove
     * @param {Event} event
     * @param {fabric.Object} element - The fabric object that has been removed.
     */
    $elem.trigger('elementRemove', [element]);
    thisClass.deselectElement();

};

/**
 * Returns an fabric object by title.
 * @param {string} title The title of an element.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.getElementByTitle = function(title) {

    var objects = stage.getObjects();
    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
        if(objects[i].title == title) {
            return objects[i];
            break;
        }
    }

};

/**
 * Sets the zoom of the stage. 1 is equal to no zoom.
 * @param {number} value The zoom value.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.setZoom = function(value) {

    thisClass.deselectElement();
    var point = new fabric.Point(stage.getWidth() * 0.5, stage.getHeight() * 0.5);
    stage.zoomToPoint(point, value);
    if(value == 1) {
        thisClass.resetZoom();
    }

};

/**
 * Resets the zoom.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.resetZoom = function() {

    thisClass.deselectElement();
    stage.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(0, 0), 1);
    stage.absolutePan(new fabric.Point(0, 0));

};

/**
 * Sets the dimensions of the stage(canvas). todo: check
 * @param {number} width The width for the stage.
 * @param {number} height The height for the stage.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.setStageDimensions = function(width, height) {

    options.width = width;
    options.stageHeight = height;

    $elem.width(width);
    $productStage.height(height * responsiveScale);
    stage.setDimensions({width: $elem.width(), height: options.stageHeight * responsiveScale})
    .calcOffset().renderAll();

    _refreshDesignerSize();

};

/**
 * Shows a message in the snackbar.
 * @param {string} text The text for the message.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.showMessage = function(text) {

    var $snackbar;

    if($body.children('.fpd-snackbar-internal').size() > 0) {
        $snackbar = $body.children('.fpd-snackbar');
    }
    else {
        $snackbar = $body.append('<div class="fpd-snackbar-internal fpd-snackbar fpd-shadow-1"><p></p></div>').children('.fpd-snackbar-internal');
    }

    $snackbar.removeClass('fpd-show-up').children('p').html(text).parent().addClass('fpd-show-up');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $snackbar.removeClass('fpd-show-up');
    }, 3000);

};

/**
 * Calls a specified content in the context dialog.
 * @param {string} target An unique target name. Possible values: 'layers', 'adds', 'products', 'saved-products', 'edit'.
 * @param {string} title The title for the context dialog, which appears in the head of the context dialog.
 * @param {string} [subTarget] An unique sub-target name. The 'adds' dialog has following sub-dialogs: 'facebook', 'instagram', 'designs'.
 * @param {boolean} [deselectElement] Deselects the current selected element.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.callDialogContent = function(target, title, subTarget, deselectElement) {

    subTarget = typeof subTarget !== 'undefined' ? subTarget : null;
    deselectElement = typeof deselectElement !== 'undefined' ? deselectElement : true;

    if(deselectElement) {
        thisClass.deselectElement();
    }

    //hide sub contents
    $contextDialog.find('.fpd-content-sub.fpd-show').removeClass('fpd-show');
    //hide content-back button
    $contextDialog.find('.fpd-content-back').removeClass('fpd-show');

    //get target div
    var $target = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-dialog-content .fpd-content-'+target);
    if($target.is(':hidden')) {
        $target.siblings('div').stop().hide()
        //show requested content div
        $target.stop().fadeIn(300);
    }

    $contextDialog.show();

    //lazy load for products
    if(target == 'products' && options.lazyLoad) {
        $currentLazyLoadContainer = $target;
        _refreshLazyLoad(false);
    }

    if(subTarget) {

        var $subTarget = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-content-sub[data-subContext="'+subTarget+'"]').addClass('fpd-show');
        $contextDialog.find('.fpd-content-back').data('parentTitle', $contextDialog.find('.fpd-dialog-title').text())
        .addClass('fpd-show');

        //lazy load for designs
        $currentLazyLoadContainer = null;
        if(subTarget == 'designs' && options.lazyLoad) {
            $currentLazyLoadContainer = $subTarget;
            _refreshLazyLoad(false);
        }

    }

    _setDialogTitle(title);

};

/**
 * Defines the current upload zone by using the title of a visible upload zone.
 * @param {string} title The title of a visible upload zone.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.setUploadZone = function(title) {

    currentUploadZone = title;
    thisClass.closeDialog();

};

/**
 * Closes the context dialog box
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.closeDialog = function() {

    $contextDialog.hide();
    $colorPicker.find('input').spectrum('hide');
    $currentLazyLoadContainer = null;
    currentUploadZone = null;

};

/**
 * Defines a clipping rectangle for an element.
 * @param {fabric.Object | string} element A fabric object or the title of an element.
 * @param {object} clippingRect Ob object containg x, y, width and height values to define the rectangle.
 * @example
 * yourDesigner.setClippingRect("Element Title", {x: 100, y: 200, width: 300, height: 400});
 * @version 3.0.2
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.setClippingRect = function(element, clippingRect) {

    //if element is string, get by title
    if(typeof element == 'string') {
        element = thisClass.getElementByTitle(element);
    }

    element.clippingRect = clippingRect;
    stage.renderAll();

};

/**
 * Sets the parameters for a specified element.
 * @param {fabric.Object | string} element A fabric object or the title of an element.
 * @param {object} parameters An object with the parameters that should be applied to the element.
 */
FancyProductDesigner.prototype.setElementParameters = function(element, parameters) {

    if(element === undefined || parameters === undefined) {
        return false;
    }

    //if element is string, get by title
    if(typeof element == 'string') {
        element = thisClass.getElementByTitle(element);
    }

    //store undos
    if(productCreated) {
        var oldParameters = {};
        for (var key in parameters) {
            oldParameters[key] = element.params[key];
        }
        undos.push({element: element, parameters: oldParameters});
    }

    //adds the element into a upload zone
    if(currentUploadZone && currentUploadZone != '') {

        parameters.z = -1;

        var uploadZoneObj = thisClass.getElementByTitle(currentUploadZone),
            bbRect = uploadZoneObj.getBoundingRect();

        $.extend(parameters, {
                boundingBox: currentUploadZone,
                scale: thisClass.getScalingByDimesions(element.getWidth(), element.getHeight(), (bbRect.width / responsiveScale)-1, (bbRect.height / responsiveScale)-1),
                autoCenter: true,
                removable: true,
                zChangeable: false,
                rotatable: uploadZoneObj.params.rotatable,
                draggable: uploadZoneObj.params.draggable,
                resizable: uploadZoneObj.params.resizable,
                price: uploadZoneObj.params.price,
                replace: currentUploadZone,
                hasUploadZone: true
            }
        );

        uploadZoneObj.opacity = 0;

    }

    //check if a upload zone contains an object
    var objects = stage.getObjects();
    for(var i=0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
        var object = objects[i];
        if(object.params && object.params.uploadZone && object.title == parameters.replace) {
            object.opacity = 0;
        }
    }

    //if topped, z-index can not be changed
    if(parameters.topped) {
        parameters.zChangeable = false;
    }

    //new element added
    if( typeof parameters.colors === 'object' ||
        parameters.removable ||
        parameters.draggable ||
        parameters.resizable ||
        parameters.rotatable ||
        parameters.zChangeable ||
        parameters.editable ||
        parameters.patternable
        || parameters.uploadZone) {

        element.isEditable = element.evented = true;
        element.set('selectable', true);


        if(element.viewIndex == currentViewIndex && $contextDialog.find('.fpd-content-layers .fpd-list-row[id="'+element.id+'"]').size() == 0) {
            _appendLayerItem(element.id, element.title, parameters.zChangeable, parameters.removable, parameters.uploadZone, !element.evented);
        }

    }

    if(parameters.opacity !== undefined) {
        element.set('opacity', parameters.opacity);
        //needs to be called for curved text
        if(element.params.curved) {
            element.setFill(element.fill);
        }
    }

    //upload zones have no controls
    if(!parameters.uploadZone || options.editorMode) {

        if(parameters.draggable) {
            element.lockMovementX = element.lockMovementY = false;
        }

        if(parameters.rotatable) {
            element.lockRotation = false;
        }

        if(parameters.resizable) {
            element.lockScalingX = element.lockScalingY = false;
        }

        if((parameters.resizable || parameters.rotatable || parameters.removable)) {
            element.hasControls = true;
        }

    }

    if(parameters.originX) {
        element.setOriginX(parameters.originX);

    }

    if(parameters.originY) {
        element.setOriginY(parameters.originY);
    }

    if(parameters.x !== undefined) {
        element.set('left', parameters.x);
    }

    if(parameters.y !== undefined) {
        element.set('top', parameters.y);
    }

    if(parameters.scale !== undefined) {
        element.set('scaleX', parameters.scale);
        element.set('scaleY', parameters.scale);
    }

    if(parameters.degree !== undefined) {
        element.set('angle', parameters.degree);
    }

    //replace element
    if(parameters.replace && parameters.replace != '' && element.viewIndex === currentViewIndex) {
        var objects = stage.getObjects();
        for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
            var object = objects[i];
            if(object.params != undefined && object.clipFor == undefined && object.params.replace == parameters.replace && object.visible && element !== object) {
                parameters.z = _getZIndex(object);
                parameters.x = object.params.x;
                parameters.y = object.params.y;
                parameters.autoCenter = false;
                thisClass.removeElement(object);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //center element
    if(parameters.autoCenter) {
        _doCentering(element);
    }

    if(parameters.flipX !== undefined) {
        element.set('flipX', parameters.flipX);
    }

    if(parameters.flipY !== undefined) {
        element.set('flipY', parameters.flipY);
    }

    if(parameters.price && !parameters.uploadZone) {
        currentPrice += parameters.price;

        /**
         * Gets fired as soon as the price has changed.
         *
         * @event FancyProductDesigner#priceChange
         * @param {Event} event
         * @param {number} elementPrice - The price of the element.
         * @param {number} totalPrice - The total price.
         */
        $elem.trigger('priceChange', [parameters.price, currentPrice]);
    }

    //change element color
    if(parameters.currentColor !== undefined && parameters.pattern == null) {
        _changeColor(element, parameters.currentColor);
    }

    //set pattern

    if(parameters.pattern !== undefined) {
        _setPattern(element, parameters.pattern);
    }

    //set filter
    if(parameters.filter) {
        element.filters = [];
        var fabricFilter = _getFabircFilter(parameters.filter);
        if(fabricFilter != null) {
            element.filters.push(fabricFilter);
        }
        element.applyFilters(function() {
            stage.renderAll();
            $body.mouseup();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the number is auto calculated by jquery. Here is the script if it helps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var yourDesigner = $('#clothing-designer').fancyProductDesigner({
            editorMode: false,
            fonts: ['Arial', 'Fearless', 'Helvetica', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana', 'Geneva', 'Gorditas'],
            customTextParameters: {
                colors: "#000000",
                removable: true,
                resizable: true,
                draggable: true,
                rotatable: true,
                autoCenter: true,
                price: 5,
                boundingBox: "ΧΡΩΜΑ"
            },
            customImageParameters: {
                draggable: true,
                removable: true,
                colors: '#000',
                autoCenter: true,
                resizable: true,
                price: 5,
                boundingBox: "ΧΡΩΜΑ"
            }
        }).data('fancy-product-designer');

        //print button
        $('#print-button').click(function(){
            yourDesigner.print();
            return false;
        });

        //create an image
        $('#image-button').click(function(){
            var image = yourDesigner.createImage();
            return false;
        });

        //create a pdf with jsPDF
        $('#pdf-button').click(function(){
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = yourDesigner.getProductDataURL('jpeg', '#ffffff');
            image.onload = function() {
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.addImage(this.src, 'JPEG', 0, 0, this.width * 0.2, this.height * 0.2);
                doc.save('Product.pdf');
            }
            return false;
        });

        //checkout button with getProduct()
        $('#checkout-button').click(function(){
            var product = yourDesigner.getProduct();
            console.log(product);
            return false;
        });

        //event handler when the price is changing
        $('#clothing-designer')
        .bind('priceChange', function(evt, price, currentPrice) {
            $('#thsirt-price').text(currentPrice);
        });

        //recreate button
        $('#recreation-button').click(function(){
            var fabricJSON = JSON.stringify(yourDesigner.getFabricJSON());
            $('#recreation-form input:first').val(fabricJSON).parent().submit();
            return false;
        });

        //click handler for input upload
        $('#upload-button').click(function(){
            $('#design-upload').click();
            return false;
        });

        //save image on webserver
        $('#save-image-php').click(function() {
            $.post( "php/save_image.php", { base64_image: yourDesigner.getProductDataURL()} );
        });

        //send image via mail
        $('#send-image-mail-php').click(function() {
            $.post( "php/send_image_via_mail.php", { base64_image: yourDesigner.getProductDataURL()} );
        });

        //upload image
        document.getElementById('design-upload').onchange = function (e) {
            if(window.FileReader) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    var image = new Image;
                    image.src = e.target.result;
                    image.onload = function() {
                        var maxH = 400,
                            maxW = 300,
                            imageH = this.height,
                            imageW = this.width,
                            scaling = 1;

                        if(imageW > imageH) {
                            if(imageW > maxW) { scaling = maxW / imageW; }
                        }
                        else {
                            if(imageH > maxH) { scaling = maxH / imageH; }
                        }

                        yourDesigner.addElement('image', e.target.result, 'my custom design', {colors: $('#colorizable').is(':checked') ? '#000000' : false, zChangeable: true, removable: true, draggable: true, resizable: true, rotatable: true, autoCenter: true, boundingBox: "ΧΡΩΜΑ", scale: scaling});
                    };
                };
            }
            else {
                alert('FileReader API is not supported in your browser, please use Firefox, Safari, Chrome or IE10!')
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the use of "boundingBox" property

Answer (score 0):

if your html is like

```
<div class="col-md-3">
PRICE <span class="price badge badge-inverse"><span id="thsirt-price">1234</span> €</span>
</div>
```

then you can do this

```
 var currentPrice = parseInt($('#thsirt-price').text().trim());
```

This must help. Let me know if your placing the number elsewhere

Comment: I did <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var currentPrice = parseInt($('#thsirt-price').text().trim());
                document.write(currentPrice);

                </script>  and the result was unfortunately NaN

Comment: Where are you placing the number?? I assumed you are placing inside `<span id="thsirt-price"></span>` element

Comment: The comment was too big so i put an answer

Comment: No problem but your answer will not be of any use to others unless you pin point where the solution is in that code.

Comment: I didn't find the answer, I am expecting one :/

Comment: Oh so you mean that was to provide more details? you can always edit your question.

Comment: Thank you I am new here.Was that piece of code helpful?I am stuck in this for 2 days

Comment: I went through it and I think you missed the part where you defin your event `'priceChange'` it has a callback function. I think it would be helpful if you can get me that code as well

Comment: Also what is the current result you get into the `thsirt-price` element after the script runs

Comment: I added the extra code in the original post.Thanks!

Comment: going through it, give me some time. btw whats the value you get now

Comment: The value I get is 15

Comment: so thats valid number right. Whats the problem in using it for your calculations?

Comment: The problem is that I can't find a way to use it.I ony can display it through that span with id="thsirt-price"

Comment: @E.S. you can retrieve it from the span and use it right. I have provided that code as well.

Comment: you said `.I ony can display it through that span with id="thsirt-price"` can you inspect the element and give me the HTML of how the span looks

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
PRICE
<span class="price badge badge-inverse" >
<span id="thsirt-price">15</span>
€
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentPrice = parseInt($('#thsirt-price').text().trim()); document.write(currentPrice);
</script>
NaN
</div>

Comment: I also added the script you provided, to see the difference

Comment: ok open the browser console and type this `$('#thsirt-price').text().trim()` . But after your span has the price 15 in it

Comment: I did it and it returns "15"

Comment: Yes, so may be when ever you are trying to fetch the value the span is still empty. put a if condition to see if the span is not empty. add this `if($('#thsirt-price').text().trim().length == 0)alert('span is empty')` before fetching the span value.